# VBA limit range to first 1000 rows

Tags: excel, range

I have the following VBA code iterating through column D of an excel spreadsheet, if the value in the cell is "x" then it hides that row. When run it works perfectly except it then lags a little after, I presume this is because it is searching every single cell in column D. I have tired to set the range to "D1:D1000" however that doesn't run. Is there any way to set this code up to only check the first 1000 cells?

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer

RowCount = 0

Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows

  If sh.Cells(rw.row, 4).Value = "x" Then
    sh.Cells(rw.row, 4).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    RowCount = RowCount + 1
  End If
Next rw

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple things you can do to boost run time

1. Toggle off Screen-Updating
2. Turn of Auto-Calculation if you have a lot of formulas on sheet
3. Instead of hiding each row 1 by 1, you can loop through the range and add target rows to a `Union` and then hide the `Union` of rows all at the same time once loop is complete.

---

```
Sub Button1_Click()

Dim sh As Worksheet: Set sh = ActiveSheet
Dim LoopRange As Range: Set LoopRange = sh.Range("D1:D1000")
Dim CurrentRow As Range

For Each CurrentRow In LoopRange
    If CurrentRow = "x" Then
        CurrentRow.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next CurrentRow

End Sub
```

Comment: I like it, simple and effective, appreciate the other tips too.

Answer (score 2):

Alternate method using an AutoFilter approach:

```
Sub Button1_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    With ws.Range("D1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))
        'Unhide all rows
        If .Parent.AutoFilterMode = True Then .Parent.AutoFilterMode = False
        .EntireRow.Hidden = False

        'Filter out to hide desired rows
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>x"
    End With

End Sub
```